# Performance of numpy.random.choice

Tags: python, performance, numpy

***I updated the code and the timings.***

I'm trying to improve the performance of a function in my code. I must generate a list with random elements. However, different parts of the list must be filled with elements taken from different sets. An example of the code is below. I must generate millions of lists like those, one at a time.

Function foo1 is the fastest, but it does not do what I need. It is there for performance reference. Functions foo2 and foo3 do what I need, but spend almost three times the processing time of foo1.

Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:29:19). [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin. numpy.**version**
'1.8.1'

```
import numpy

import timeit

_ops_1 = ["-123.456", "3.1416", "1", "2"]
_ops_2 = ["ABC", "XYZ", 'A', 'B', 'C']

size = 10

def foo1 (): 
    return numpy.random.choice(_ops_1 + _ops_2, 5*size)

def foo2 (): 
    return list(numpy.concatenate((numpy.random.choice(_ops_1, 2*size), 
        numpy.random.choice(_ops_1 + _ops_2, size),
        numpy.random.choice(_ops_2, 2*size)), 0))

def foo3 (): 
    return numpy.random.choice(_ops_1, 2*size).tolist() + \
        numpy.random.choice(_ops_1 + _ops_2, size).tolist() + \
        numpy.random.choice(_ops_2, 2*size).tolist()

### Suggested by Divakar
def random_choice_replace_True(arr,size):
    return numpy.take(arr,numpy.random.randint(0,len(arr),size))

def foo4 (): 
    return random_choice_replace_True(_ops_1, 2*size).tolist() + \
        random_choice_replace_True(_ops_1 + _ops_2, size).tolist() + \
        random_choice_replace_True(_ops_2, 2*size).tolist()

### 2nd suggestion by Divakar
def random_choice_replace_True_idx(arr,size):
    return numpy.array(arr)[numpy.random.randint(0,len(arr),size)]

def foo5 (): 
    return random_choice_replace_True_idx(_ops_1, 2*size).tolist() + \
        random_choice_replace_True_idx(_ops_1 + _ops_2, size).tolist() + \
        random_choice_replace_True_idx(_ops_2, 2*size).tolist()

###########

setup = '''import numpy

_ops_1 = ["-123.456", "3.1416", "1", "2"]
_ops_2 = ["ABC", "XYZ", 'A', 'B', 'C']

size = 10'''

# As required, Number was increased to 10 million to get closer to actual timings
timeit.timeit(foo1, setup=setup, number=10000000)

timeit.timeit(foo2, setup=setup, number=10000000)

timeit.timeit(foo3, setup=setup, number=10000000)

timeit.timeit(foo4, setup=setup, number=10000000)

timeit.timeit(foo5, setup=setup, number=10000000)
```

The running times on my machine were:

> timeit.timeit(foo1, setup=setup, number=10000000)
>   235.22050380706787
>
> timeit.timeit(foo2, setup=setup, number=10000000)
>   760.1884841918945
>
> timeit.timeit(foo3, setup=setup, number=10000000)
>   560.77258586883545
>
> timeit.timeit(foo4, setup=setup, number=10000000)
>   388.69550228118896
>
> timeit.timeit(foo5, setup=setup, number=10000000)
>   252.32089233398438

Well, for now I'll take the 2nd suggestion made by Divakar, which is pretty good. But other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: So your code is faster than 1s and you *need* to improve the performance? With runtimes that low the runtime will vary a lot depending on what your system is doing right now (background processes). I don't know if your problem is even a problem.

Comment: If you share the actual problem (how you generate millions of lists) it might be easier to optimize.

Comment: As required, I updated the code and the timings.

Answer (score 2):

That [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with its optional argument `replace` being set as `True` returns randomly chosen elements from the input array and the elements could be repeated. We can simulate such a behavior by creating random indices covering the length of the array and indexing into the array for the selection. Thus, we can simulate that built-in with something like this -

```
def random_choice_replace_True(A,size):
    return np.array(A)[np.random.randint(0,len(A),size)]
```

If you are dealing with inputs that are already NumPy arrays, you can skip the `np.array(A)` part for conversion and simply use `A` there.

Comment: Dear Divakar. Thanks for your suggestion. It considerably improved the performance.  It would be great to improve it even further.

Comment: @user1348438 I have replaced `numpy.take` with simple indexing, which according to some tests that I just ran seem to be shaving off a bit more of the runtime. Check those out! Also, I don't think I can optimize it any further :)

Comment: Dear Divakar. Thanks for the suggestion. It is much better now! Best regards.