# Python: random.choice and MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy, memory, out-of-memory

I have the following code and relative error

```
np.random.choice(np.random.normal(1,1,299), size=(10000, 10000), replace=True)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "mtrand.pyx", line 1434, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
>   (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:17437)   File "mtrand.pyx", line 1266,
>   in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:15790)
>   File "mtrand.pyx", line 1267, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
>   (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:15595)   File "mtrand.pyx", line 722, in
>   mtrand._rand_int32 (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10408) MemoryError

I have seen that questions on this topic are quite outdated. Which is in your opinion the most efficient way to solve?

Comment: How about this one - [`Performance of numpy.random.choice
`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376220) ?

Comment: How much memory do you have?  The return value of the call will require 800 MB, and the code that generates it uses a temporary array of integers with the same number of elements, which is another 400 MB or 800 MB (depending on the size of an integer on your system).

Comment: But my laptop is 8 GB of RAM. Could it be that my Python version is 32 bit?

Comment: What is the output of `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)`?

Comment: It is 2147483647

Comment: That's 32 bit (`2147483647 == 2**31 - 1`).

Comment: I change to Python 64 bit, unfortunately the problem resists even if now I have
9223372036854775807

Comment: Does this work: `np.random.randint(1,299,size=(10000,10000))`?  I have the same maxsize and your choice expression works, even in a long running ipython session.

Comment: Actually that was a simplified example. My real code is `np.random.choice(vector, size=(10000, 10000), replace=True)`